# Can client.args be passed to karma test specs?

Tags: karma-runner

From https://github.com/karma-runner/grunt-karma,

> Using additional client.args
>
> You can pass arbitrary client.args through the commandline like this:
>
> $ grunt karma:dev watch --grep=mypattern

Can the client args be used in the test specs?  How to access such values?

Answer (score 0):

The answer in this question could help [karma start - passing parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38876237/karma-start-passing-parameters)

To quote it here, you can do

```
it("get karma args", function () {
    console.log(__karma__.config.args);
});
```