# karma start - passing parameters

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

Is there a way to pass a parameter thru the Karma command line and then read that somewhere in your tests? For instance, this is what want:

```
karma start -branding="clientX"
```

And then somewhere in my specs I would need to access this variable (I need the "clientX" value).

Is this possible at all?

Comment: see https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/672 2nd-to-last post

Comment: @JeremyKahan still unable to get it working :(

Comment: karma start --BRANDING clientX on the command line (note --, no =, no quotes). And in karma.conf.js module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({ brand: config.BRANDING,

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It is possible to transmit parameters to test cases. It can be a bit tricky. What you can to do is check for `__karma__.config.args` in you test suite:

```
it("get karma args", function () {
    console.log(__karma__.config.args);
});
```

#### `karma run`

If you want to pass arguments with `karma run`, then the above is all you need.

Then if you do `karma start` and then `karma run -- --foo` you should see on the console:

```
LOG: ['--foo']
```

Note how the argument passed to `karma run` ended up in `__karma__.config.args`. Also note that the first double-dash in `karma run -- --foo` is there to separate Karma arguments from "client arguments" it is necessary. (`karma start` does not make the same distinction.)

#### `karma start`

`karma start` works differently.

If you use a default `karma.conf.js` created by `karma init`, you won't be able to pass arguments in this way by doing `karma start --single-run --foo`. You need to modify your `karma.conf.js` to pass the arguments:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    client: {
        args: config.foo ? ["--foo"] : [],
    },
```

If you run `karma start --single-run --foo`, then you'll get the same input as with `run` earlier.

If I had to pass multiple arguments, I'd scan `process.argv` to filter out those parts of it that are only for Karma's benefit and pass the rest to `args` instead of testing for each possibility.

You may have inferred from the above that when you `karma start --single-run --something` the argument ends up as `config.something` in `karma.conf.js`.

#### Complete example

This example was tested against Karama 1.1.x and Karma 1.2.0. It shows the same method I've discussed above to get command line parameters to transit through `client.args`. This works both with `karma start` and `karma run`. I also added a method to pass values without going through `client.args` (that's the `branding` example). However, this method does not work with `karma run`.

`karma.conf.js`:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    client: {
        // Example passing through `args`.
        args: config.foo ? ["--foo"] : [],

        // It is also possible to just pass stuff like this,
        // but this works only with `karma start`, not `karma run`.
        branding: config.branding,
    },
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    files: [
      'test/**/*.js'
    ],
    exclude: [],
    preprocessors: {},
    reporters: ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

`test/test.js`:

```
it("get karma arg", function () {
    console.log("BRANDING", __karma__.config.branding);
    console.log("ARGS", __karma__.config.args);
});
```

If you run `karma start --single-run --foo --branding=q`, you get:

```
LOG: 'BRANDING', 'q'
LOG: 'ARGS', ['--foo']
```

If you start Karma and then use `karma run -- --foo --branding=q`, you get:

```
LOG: 'BRANDING', undefined
LOG: 'ARGS', ['--foo', '--branding=q']
```

As mentioned above, when using `karma run`, everything must go through `config.args` to be visible in the test.

Comment: hey i want to pass multiple arguments how can i pass that? In client.args for --grep=foo1, foo2 how should i pass? like this but it is not working (, args: ['--grep= foo1, foo2'])

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. All you have to do is specify that parameter in `client` section of `karma.conf.js` :

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: '',
        frameworks: ['jasmine'],
        plugins: [
            ...
        ],
        client: { //Put the parameters here
            codeCoverage: config.cc,
            testSuite: config.testSuite
        },
...
```

To pass it:

```
karma start --cc --testSuite=sanity
```

Note that if you don't give a value to parameter (like `--cc`) it will be set to `true`.

To access it from the tests:

```
console.log('Coverage: ', __karma__.config.codeCoverage);
console.log('Test suite: ', __karma__.config.testSuite);
```