# Pass karma programmatically arguments

Tags: jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I am using karma with jasmine and the jasmine-spec-tags framework. When starting karma from CLI I use "karma start --tags=MY_TAG" to run only some tests with the tag MY_TAG. This works fine.

Now, I need to start karma **programmatically**. I tried the following code (note the `client.args` value at the end):

```
const server = new Server(
{
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: [
        'Chrome',
    ],
    files: [
        './node_modules/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.js',
        './node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js',
        './karma/karma.entry.js'
    ],
    frameworks: ['jasmine', 'jasmine-spec-tags'],
    phantomJsLauncher: {
        exitOnResourceError: true
    },
    port: 9876,
    preprocessors: {
        './karma/karma.entry.js': ['webpack', 'sourcemap']
    },
    reporters: ['dots'],
    singleRun: false,
    webpack: webpackConf,
    webpackServer: {
        noInfo: true
    },
    client:
    {
        args: ['--tags=SchedulingApiService']
    }
});

server.start();
```

This does not work. Am I misunderstanding the `client.args` value? Would be glad about any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [karma start - passing parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38876237/karma-start-passing-parameters)

Comment: Bolding "programmatically" changes nothing to the fact that your question is a duplicate. The problem and the solution is exactly the same whether you rely on a configuration file or start karma programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, the `client` part has to look like this:

```
client:
{
    tags: 'SchedulingApiService'
}
```